# CS1003 Error in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, compiler-errors, runtime-error

The following line generates a CS1003 error in ASP.NET MVC 3:

```
@model Int32 // user ID
```

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

The CS1003 error is a general symptom of a failure by MVC to parse the Razor syntax. It could be caused by many things.

One thing I've noticed is that this problem will occur if you try to use a C# style single-line comment to annotate the model declaration in a Razor view:

```
BAD:  @model Int32 // user ID

GOOD: @* user ID *@
      @model Int32
```

Visual Studio syntax highlighting won't flag it as a problem, but it will fail at runtime.